# How to make multi-level dropdown span across entire navbar with consisten background

Tags: html, css

I have been working to make a multi-level dropdown navbar, and when the dropdown finally started working, the rest of the navigation broke.

I'm trying to get a navbar with a width of 100% of the body, and then a container that is 80% of the body

```
#nav {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
 }
.container {
   width: 80%;
 }
```

However, after getting the dropdown to work, the background color of the nav (red) is no longer showing, and the grey area of the dropdown lists only spans across a much smaller area.

How can I get the dropdown/navigation lists to sit within the container (80% of body) while keeping the span all the way across the 100% width of the body? Note, the colors don't matter so much right now, just getting the right distance setup.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/RwwMLwX)

And the snippet

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
}

.third-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -150px;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.third-level-menu > li {
  height: auto;
  background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #cccccc;
}

.second-level-menu {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.second-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #cccccc;
}

.top-level-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}

.top-level-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #cccccc;
}

.top-level-menu li:hover > ul {
  display: inline;
}

.top-level-menu a {
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Offices</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">New York</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The elements in your navigation are floated, or have absolute position, which takes them out of the text flow that would otherwise give your nav element height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **CSS** to look like this:

```
#nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; // setting left and right to 0px will make the container take up the entire page
    right: 0px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Also, if you want your elements in the navbar centred, add the following lines of code to your current stylesheet.

```
.container{
    margin: 0 auto; // center the container
}
.top-level-menu{
    width: 100%; // make the width of the menu 100% of the container
}
.top-level-menu li{
    width: 25%; // make the width of each li element 25% of the container (100% / 4 li = 25%)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear float

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

add clearfix class to top-level-menu